# the correct regex for replacing em-dash with a basic "-" in java

Tags: java

My question concerns the replaceAll method of String class.

My purpose is to replace all the em-dashes in a text with a basic "-".
I know the unicode character of em-dash is \u2014.

I tried it in the following way:

```
String s = "asd – asd";
s = s.replaceAll("\u2014", "-");
```

Still, the em-dash is not replaced. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are replacing \u2014 with - in the string asd – asd, where no \u2014 string is found

Comment: there is one, created and copied one directly from ms word

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Minor edit after question edit:

You might not be using an em-dash at all. If you're not sure what you have, a nice solution is to simply find and replace all dashes... em or otherwise. Take a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045511/matching-unicode-dashes-in-java-regular-expressions), you can try to use the **[Unicode dash punctuation property](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/)** for all dashes ==> `\\p{Pd}`

```
String s = "asd – asd";
s = s.replaceAll("\\p{Pd}", "-");
```

---

**[Working example](http://ideone.com/MdaPd)** replacing an em dash and regular dash both with the above code.

**References:**
**[`public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)**
**[Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/)**

Comment: Tried it in the both ways. Still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: *Warning:* `\p{Pd}` matches dashes other than just horizontal ones, see [Unicode Characters in the 'Punctuation, Dash' Category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm).

Comment: It doesn't replace em-dash

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you posted, the problem may not actually lie with your code, but with your assumed dash. What you have looks like an en dash (width of a capital N) rather than an em dash (width of a capital M). The Unicode for the en dash is U+2013, try using that instead and see if it updates properly.

Answer (score 2):

`String.replaceAll` takes a regex as its first parameter. If you just want to replace all occurences of a single char by another char, consider using [`String.replace(char, char)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
String s = "asd – asd";
s = s.replace('\u2014', '-');
```

Comment: thanks for a suggestion. Tried it out, but still didnt replace the em-dash.

Answer (score 1):

[It works fine for me](http://ideone.com/32hQS). My guess is you're not using an em-dash. Test copy-pasting the em-dash character from the character map instead of word.