# Replace long dash with a usual one in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string with multiple dashes, but it contains long dashes.

What method can I use to normalize dashes?

```cs
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(\u2012|\u2013|\u2014|\u2015)", "-");
```

The expected output is something like `11-1111-11/11`
The actual is almost the same, but some of the dashes are long ones. (I can't put in that dash because the stackoverflow does not recognize it.)
[image]

Comment: If you're able to copy and paste that "extremely long" dash into the replace statement, then that should work just fine. Shouldn't even need `regex`

Comment: Cannot. Cant paste to the C# file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Examine `text` in the debugger. Look at the unicode value of the dashes that aren't getting replaced. Add those code(s) to your regex.

Comment: Why can't you paste? What error do you get?

Comment: No error, just when i paste it it replaced to usual dash

Comment: I was able to paste the mdash in VS. Check your file encoding.

Comment: VS works with any Unicode characters just fine. If it's not then you're not using a Unicode encoding

Comment: I don't get it why is this duplicate if it's C# the other one question is JAVA... not the same

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
 private const string DashPattern = @"[\u2012\u2013\u2014\u2015]";
 private static Regex _dashRegex = new Regex(DashPattern);

 public static string RemoveLongDashes(string s)
 {
     return _dashRegex.Replace(s, "-");
 }
```

Your expression with the pipe characters (`|`) is not a valid regex expression.  If you want to replace all of the vowels, you use an expression like `@"[aeiou]"`, i.e., the choices within a set of square brackets.

Comment: I'm intrigued why this was down-voted.  It provides a way to convert all of the various Unicode dash characters (Figure Dash, En Dash, Em Dash and Horizontal Bar (U+2012 through U+2015)) into a plain old ASCII-ish hyphen.  That was the gist of the original question

Comment: Thanks man... this should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is some info on the em dash. You might be able to copy and paste the dash from this post into your code and use the string.replace

[The em dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357622/whats-the-ascii-character-code-for)

Look in the following SO post for the answer:

[replacing the em dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203852/the-correct-regex-for-replacing-em-dash-with-a-basic-in-java)

Looks like the following code solved the issue for others:

```
String s = "asd – asd";
s = s.replaceAll("\\p{Pd}", "-");
```