# Searching for all variations of hyphens and dashes in Regex

Tags: regex

I have been trying to extract certain text from PDF converted into text files. The PDF came from various sources and I don't know how they were generated.

The pattern I was trying to extract was a simply two digits, follows by a hyphen, and then another two digits, e.g. 12-34.  So I wrote a simple regex `\d\d-\d\d` and expected that to work.

However when I test it I found that it missed some hits.  Later I noted that there are at least two hyphens represented as `\u2212` and `\xad`.  So I changed my regex to `\d\d[-\u2212\xad]\d\d` and it worked.

My question is, since I am going to extract so many PDF that I don't know what other variations of hyphen are out there, is there any regex expression covering all "hyphens", and hopefully looks better than the `[-\u2212\xad]` expression?

Comment: No, you must indeed decide what characters count as "hyphen" and include them manually. Also, `U+2212` is not a hyphen (it's a mathematical minus) and neither is `U+00AD` (this is a soft "breaking" hyphen).

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanks for your comment, but I don't want to distinguish them as long as they looks like a hyphen. I cannot control the input as they were converted from various PDF files. So is there any regex representation for "anything that looks like a hyphen, a minus, an em dash, an en dash or similar character"?

Comment: `\p{Pd}` from [matching-unicode-dashes-in-java-regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045511/matching-unicode-dashes-in-java-regular-expressions)

Comment: @KennethL, if you don't mind to distinguish a hyphen from a mathematica minus sign, and only want to match _anything that remotely resembles a hyphen_ why not use `\d\d.\d\d` as your regexp (this will match all possible hyphens available in unicode ---and what are not hyphens also, but they can resemble a hyphen, depending how open your mind is :) )

Comment: @LuisColorado thanks for your suggestion for `\d\d.\d\d` but I need to exclude patterns like `12345`. Thanks for reminding that I can change my requirement as well.

Comment: @KennethL, then use `\d\d\D\d\d` and next ask for how to match `12334.4566`.  If I had an answer to this question I should have published one... don't take me seriously in these comments.  Btw, how your proposed regex behaves with things like `1234456-23453445`  does it get `56-23` only?  Is that valid? where do you put the actual requirements?

Comment: @LuisColorado Truly appreciate your input.  Yes `1234456-23453445` get `56-23` matches my expectation as well. The accepted answer below gave me a reasonably good solution indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution you ask for in the question title implies a *whitelisting* approach and means that you need to find the chars that you think are similar to hyphens.

You may refer to the [*Punctuation, Dash Category*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm), that Unicode cateogry lists all the Unicode hyphens possible.

You may use a [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) and use `\p{Pd}` pattern to match any Unicode hyphen.

Or, if you can only work with `re`, use

```
[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]
```

You may expand this list with other Unicode chars that contain `minus` in their Unicode names, see [this list](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=-%C2%B1%CB%97%CC%A0%E2%81%92%E2%81%BB%E2%82%8B%E2%88%92%E2%88%93%E2%88%96%E2%88%B8%E2%89%82%E2%8A%96%E2%8A%9F%E2%A4%BC%E2%A8%A9%E2%A8%AA%E2%A8%AB%E2%A8%AC%E2%A8%BA%E2%A9%81%E2%A9%AC%EF%B9%A3%EF%BC%8D%F3%A0%80%AD).

A *blacklisting* approach means you do not want to match specific chars between the two pairs of digits. If you want to match any non-whitespace, you may use `\S`. If you want to match any punctuation or symbols, use `(?:[^\w\s]|_)`.

**Note** that the "soft hyphen", U+00AD, is not included into the `\p{Pd}` category, and won't get matched with that construct. To include it, create a character class and add it:

```
[\xAD\p{Pd}]
[\xAD\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]
```

Comment: ... and even chinese symbols that resemble a hyphen, or anything that remotely resembles a hyphen, as `_` underscore, or `=` equal sign, or `¬` logic negation, or `~`  tilde (well, it resembles vaguely a hyphen), right?

Comment: @LuisColorado Whatever OP wants to include into the list of "chars resembling a hyphen".

Comment: I'm afraid, any of the samples I've put is not in your list (and in the Punctuation Dash cathegory there are double hyphens ---excluding the equals mathematical sign---, and the `WAVE DASH` ---which resembles a tilde, that has another codepoint---) I think using `\d\d\D\d\d` should give better results once reached this point.

Comment: @LuisColorado I answered the problem stated in the question title. I see your point, but in that case, I would not use `.` (as in your comment to the question) as it may match a digit, nor `\D` as it may match whitespace. In this case, a `\d\d(?:[^\w\s]|_)\d\d` to match a char other than whitespace, letters and digits between two pairs of digits. Basically, `(?:[^\w\s]|_)` matches any punctuation and symbols.

Comment: Well, the comment is not a comment for you, but for the OP.  The problem here is that the question is so ambiguous that it's very difficult to state what should be considered a hyphen, mostly in unicode terms.  **You have done a very good work** searching for them, but my comment was not for you.  Case I had a good answer, I would have written one, and not only put comments to other answers. Even in the case you present, a sequence like `1234-5678` would be matched as `34-56` (which I assume bad behaviour) so consider it as a difficult question to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is also a possible solution, if your regex engine allows it

`/\p{Dash}/u`

This will include all [these characters](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B:Dash=Yes:%5D).