# Combining several replace-statements into one in pandas­

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

There is a `DataFrame` in pandas, see image below

[image: input]

Basically it is a table **scraped** from Wikipedia's article: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Gro%C3%9Fst%C3%A4dte_in_Deutschland#Tabelle

For further processing, I am trying to clean up the data. So, these statements work well

```py
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('\d+', '')
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.strip()
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(',', '')
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('­-', '')
```

But how can I bring all these four statements into one? Probably using regular expressions.

I tried with `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'[\d\-,]+', '')` but it did not work. Maybe because of the word wrap character that was used.

My desired output is `" Ber,li-n2  "`-> `"Berlin"`.

The unknown circumstances are going around 'Mönchen­gladbach1, 5'.

Comment: `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'[\d\-,]+', '')` should work. Or `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'[\d,-]+', '').str.strip()`

Comment: `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('(\d+|,|-|<­)', '')`

Comment: I added all Unicode dashes to the solution in my answer.

Comment: You can put the `-`into the Regex-Group as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the data, so you may join the patterns you remove into a single pattern like the one you have. `r'[\d,-]+'` is a bit better stylistically.

You may remove any [dash punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923599/searching-for-all-unicode-variation-of-hyphens-in-python) + soft hyphen (`\u00AD`) using `[\u00AD\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]`, so you may want to add these codes to the regex.

Remember to assign the cleaned data back to the column and add `.str.stip()`.

You may use

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'[\u00AD\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D\d,-]+', '').str.strip()
```

If you do not want to add `str.strip()`, add `^\s+` and `\s+$` alternatives to the regex:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'^\s+|[\u00AD\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D\d,-]+|\s+$', '')
```

**Details**

- `^\s+` - 1+ whitespaces at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D\d,-]+` - 1 or more Unicode dashes, digits, commas or `-` chars
- `|` - or
- `\s+$` - 1+ whitespaces at the end of the string.

Comment: I do not know why but it still does not work with bloody `'Mönchen­gladbach1, 5'`, see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Gro%C3%9Fst%C3%A4dte_in_Deutschland#Tabelle).

Comment: @Taras There is an invisible char, here, `\u00AD`, soft hyphen, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Dziękuję bardzo! Works like a charm! Can you be so kind and tell me a little bit more about  this "invisible" char? or refer me to a source.

Comment: @Taras I copied your string and pasted into https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ convert field, then I instantly saw the char and its code. [\u00AD](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%AD) belongs to `\p{Cf}` category, no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('(\d+|,|­<|>|-)', '')
```

Put the items you want to sort out into a group, and seperate different options using the pipe `|`

Comment: I do not know why but it still does not work with bloody `'Mönchen­gladbach1, 5'`, see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Gro%C3%9Fst%C3%A4dte_in_Deutschland#Tabelle).

Comment: In case you want a simple conversion from `Mönchen­gladbach1, 5` to `Mönchen­gladbach`, this statement works. But its hard to say how it behaves for you, without knowing the exact output of your `df`. Taking a look at the link, i can see that there is a linbreak between `Mönchen` and `gladbach`. Either add it as `\n` to the group of items to be replaces, or put your df into the question, so we can have a look at it.