# Is it possible to specify Unicode category classes for Notepad++ regex expressions?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Notepad++ provides a number of class names that seem to match the Unicode equivalents when used in regex expressions. For example, \p{upper} in Notepad++ corresponds to \p{Lu} in many other regex flavours. Is it possible to specify in the Notepad++ more restricted Unicode categories, such as the equivalent for \p{Pd} =  "punctuation dash" (\p{punct} is too inclusive)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way at least for the time being.

Use an alternative:

```
[\xAD\x2D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]
```

It matches all [`\p{Pd}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923599/searching-for-all-unicode-variation-of-hyphens-in-python) + a soft hyphen (`\xAD`) that is not part of `\p{Pd}`.