# Why is re.findall behaving like this? (python regex)

Tags: python, regex

I made a small program in pyhton that searches through a music website and collects music data. The music has a format of `[artist] - [music name] [music file format]`. At first I used `re.search` to find a certain artist (I used regex because there are some other characters and irregularities in the music info above, and the only indicator for finding the artist was the `-` following the artist).

Somehow it didn't work so I changed it to `re.findall` just in case but it still didn't work. since I'm a beginner at python I thought I sis something wrong so I wrote some test code to study what was wrong. And this is what I got.

[image: already imported re]

when I changed the `x` string (which would be the music info) and ran `re.findall` again it gave me a different result(none). I 100% thought the result would be the same. why is this behaving like this? And could this be the reason why my original code's `re.serach`, `re.findall` wasn't working?

I've included the code just in case. (used selenium)

```
idx = 1
while True:
        try:
            hxp1 = "(//h3[@class='entry-title td-module-title']/a)[" + str(idx) + "]" 

            text = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, hxp1)))

            # info = eg) 'Michael Jackson - Beat it [FLAC, MP3, WAV]'
            info = text.get_attribute('title') # get 'info' as string
            
            # ARTIST = eg) 'Michael Jackson'
            regex = ARTIST + ' - '
            match = re.findall(regex, info) # or use re.search
            
            # do something with 'match'...

            idx += 1

        except:
            # do something...
            break
```

Comment: Two things: 1) are you sure the `-` is a hyphen and not some Unicode (e[mn]-)?dash? 2) Are you sure the spaces are regular spaces and not some hard spaces? Try `Minami\s[-—–]\s`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you `Minami\s[-—–]\s` works. May I ask the difference between hard and regular space? And also what does `[---]` mean?

Comment: There are 20 different space characters in Unicode.  https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

Comment: @Maxjo there are multiple different text characters that may look like dashes to you, or like blank spaces, of varying widths depending on not only the font you use, but the context in which the text is written. Your regex can only replace the text if it looks for the version that the text actually contains. `[-—–]` that you copied and pasted is **not the same text as** the `[---]` that you typed by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to make sure you match

- any Unicode whitespaces (i.e. `\s` in Python 3.x, or `(?u)\s` in Python 2.x, see [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html): "*Matches Unicode whitespace characters (which includes `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`, and also many other characters, for example the non-breaking spaces mandated by typography rules in many languages).*")
- any Unicode hyphens (see [Searching for all Unicode variation of hyphens in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48923599/3832970)).

Combining all that into your regex:

```py
Minami\s[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]\s
```

In your case, if you just need to support en-dash/em-dash/hyhen chars and any Unicode whitespace chars, you can use

```py
Minami\s[-—–]\s
```

Comment: Another possibility is to [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode) the string first.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel When the task is to check if there is a  match or not, yes. If the string needs to be extracted, then it depends on the requirements.