# Detect specific pattern regex python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I want to find all the occurrences of an specific term (and its variations) in a word document.

1. Extracted the text from the word document
2. Try to find pattern via regex

The pattern consists of words that start with DOC- and after the - there are 9 digits.

I have tried the following without success:

document variable is the extracted text with the following function:

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

1. pattern = re.compile('^DOC.\d{9}$')
2. pattern.findall(document)

pattern.findall(document)

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, document variable is the extracted text

Comment: Try without `^` and `$` and also escape `.`(Using `\.`)

Comment: Tried pattern = re.compile('DOC\.\d{9}') but no success

Comment: Can you update the question with sample text(Ie, `document`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combinbation of word and numeric right-hand boundaries.

Also, you say there must be a dash after `DOC`, but you use a `.` in the pattern. I believe you wanted to also match any en- or em-dash, so I'd suggest to use a more precise pattern, like `[-–—]`. Note there are other ways to match any Unicode dash char, see [Searching for all Unicode variation of hyphens in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48923599/3832970).

```py
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

print( re.findall(r'\bDOC[-–—]\d{9}(?!\d)', getText(filename)) )
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `DOC` - `DOC` substring
- `[-–—]` - a dash symbol (hyphen, en- or em-dash)
- `\d{9}` - nine digits
- `(?!\d)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be no digit.