# Use regex to find page numbers in two different format

Tags: python, regex

I've many string that have two possible format to display page numbers: `(pp. 4500-4503)` or just `4500-4503` (there may be also cases where I have only one page so `(pp. 113)` or just `11` .

Some exemples of strings:

```
- Mitchell, J.A. (2017). Citation: Why is it so important. Mendeley Journal, 67(2), (pp. 81-95). 

- Denhart, H. (2008). Deconstructing barriers: Perceptions of students labeled with learning disabilities in higher education. Journal of Learning Disabilities, 41, 483-497.
```

I'm using this regex for the first format:

```
r"pp\. \d+-\d+"
```

And this for the second one:

```
r"\d+-\d+"
```

Neither of them are working. I was also wondering: is there a way to use only one regex expression instead of creating two?
Thank you

Comment: Your patterns seem to be working. To create a single pattern, you can use an optional non capture group `(?:pp\. )?\d+-\d+` https://regex101.com/r/KOokjR/1

Comment: Neither works, that is strange. Are you sure the hyphen is a regular hyphen? Try `re.findall(r"(?:\bpp\.\s*)?\d+[—–-]\d+", text)`. Note that `\s` matches *any* Unocode whitespace in Python `re` and the `[—–-]` pattern will match en-dash, em-dash and the hyphen. Here you can find all possible [Unicode dash patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48923796/3832970).

Comment: Thank you! It works  for the `(pp. number-number)` format but not for the `number-numbe`r one. Also I've changed it to `r"\((?:pp\. )\)?\d+-\d+"` to have the "()", but I don't know why I'm only getting `(pp. number-number` without the last one  `)`. It also come to my mind that there may be the occurance where I have only one digit number when there is only a page. How could I change the code for that occurance? thanks again

Comment: `re.findall(r"(?:\(?\bpp\.\s*)?\d+(?:[—–-]\d+)?\)?", text)`?

Comment: You can match both like this `\(pp\. \d+(?:-\d+)?\)|\b\d+-\d+\b` https://regex101.com/r/h53rOT/1

Comment: `or just 11` How do you know that 11 or a single number is a page number?

Comment: Thank you all! `r"(?:\bpp\.\s*)?\d+[—–-]\d+"` is working perfectly for the `(pp. number-number)` format but I'm having problem with the `number-number` one since it gives me back also numbers inside a url. Usually the page numbers follow a commas and then there is a dot (like this: `, number-number.` ) How can I change the code according to this? Same goes for when there is only one page listed `, number.`  and the ` (pp. number)` format. Thank you all for your help. Is the first time I’m working with regex and I’m a little bit lost. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
\(pp\.\s+\d+(?:-\d+)?\)|\b\d+(?:-\d+)?(?=(?:\s*,\s*\d+(?:-\d+)?)*\.)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(pp\.\s+\d+(?:-\d+)?\)`
- `|` Or
- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+(?:-\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and optionally `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\s*,\s*` Match a comma between optional whitespace chars
    - `\d+(?:-\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and optionally `-` and 1+ digits
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
  - `\.`
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XnWJsT/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5FUP4j).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"\(pp\.\s+\d+(?:-\d+)?\)|\b\d+(?:-\d+)?(?=(?:\s*,\s*\d+(?:-\d+)?)*\.)"

s = ("- Mitchell, J.A. (2017). Citation: Why is it so important. Mendeley Journal, 67(2), (pp. 81-95). \n\n"
            "- Denhart, H. (2008). Deconstructing barriers: Perceptions of students labeled with learning disabilities in higher education. Journal of Learning Disabilities, 41, 483-497.")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['(pp. 81-95)', '41', '483-497']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I only had to edit it a little bit since I have found out that sometimes my hyphen is not really an hypen and to remove the occurence between the two commas since right now I need only to find out number between commas and dot. This is how I edited the code: `r"\(pp\.\s+\d+(?:[—–-]\d+)?\)|\b\d+(?:[—–-]\d+)?(?=(?:\d+(?:[—–-]\d+)?)*\.)"` it seems to work fine but I'd like to ask someone more expert if I can use it this way. Thanks again!

Comment: @DianaMele In that case you can shorten the pattern to `\(pp\.\s+\d+(?:[—–-]\d+)?\)|\b\d+(?:[—–-]\d+)?(?=\.)` See https://regex101.com/r/8Gy9Yg/1

Answer (score 1):

This pattern matches all your different formats:

```
(\(pp\.)? \d+(-\d+)?\)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/HV7rlJ/2